# Move characters between two strings to end of line

Tags: linux, text-editing

I need to move (in a text file) all the characters between ">" up to and including "_" to the end of that line.

From this:

```
[[[>AVA_M427014_
MAKNISRTAQMRVAIEEL

>AVB_L427D15_
MSGATSRTGNLRKEIEELVLT

>GVB_F83R906_
MAKIRANIPELLCAGVT

s004
5039.1
40403
```

to this:

```
[[[>M427014_AVA_
MAKNISRTAQMRVAIEEL

>L427D15_AVB_
MSGATSRTGNLRKEIEELVLT

>F83R906_GVB_
MAKIRANIPELLCAGVT

s004
5039.1
40403
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/>\([^_]*_\)\(.*\)$/>\2\1/' file
#    s/                  /     / search and replace
#                                search for
#      >                         literal >
#       \(      \)\(  \)         two blocks
#         [^_]*                  anything but _, zero or more characters
#              _                 literal _
#                   .*           zero or more characters
#                       $        end of line
#                                replace with
#                         >      literal >
#                          \2\1  the second block, then the first block
```

Use `sed -i` to edit the file in place.